# Заглавные буквы в псевдонимах

Tags: орфография

Недавно я узнал, что в псевдонимах и прозвищах все слова надо писать с заглавной буквы. Не означает ли это, что такие псевдонимы Чехова, как "Брат моего брата" и "Человек без селезёнки", следовало бы писать "Брат Моего Брата" и "Человек Без Селезёнки"? И вообще, не будет ли ошибкой, если я подпишусь псевдонимом, состоящим из нескольких нарицательных слов, не все из которых я напишу с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1):

По современным правилам, нужно писать все слова с большой буквы. Но нельзя утверждать, что во времена Чехова все правила были такими же, как и сейчас.

Самое важное — сохранить аутентичность названия, то, как писали тогда. Это история. Поэтому на сайте Грамоты иногда используют фразу "историческое название".

А придумывая новый псевдоним, следует писать все слова с большой буквы.

С другой стороны, сейчас есть логины (своего рода псевдонимы), для которых вообще никакие правила не действуют.

Comment: Кстати, насчёт логинов. Собираюсь взять себе логин с предлогом "в". Если никакие правила не действуют, значит, в логине можно смело писать маленькую "в"?

Comment: Да, я с маленькой написал свой логин. Это делают очень часто. Но логин - это не полноценный псевдоним. Он не подойдёт для писателя, певца, исторического деятеля.